# How does C++ resolve this return type?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, operator-overloading, return

I was reading [this article about parallel programming](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/02/04/sorting-data-in-parallel-cpu-gpu/) and I came across a `return` statement that I don't quite understand. I've read about [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29) and [Boost::Chrono::steady_clock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock), though I've never used either in practice, I understand their purposes.

This is the line of code found in the `run_tests` function which puzzles me:

```
return boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (end - start).count();
```

What's going on here exactly? Shouldn't an object name come before `.count()`? Is there some overloading of the `-` operator in Chrono?

[The full code can be found here](https://github.com/sol-prog/Sort_data_parallel/blob/master/parallel_sort_CPU.cpp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
       boost::chrono::duration
```

is the name of a class template.

```
       boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli>
```

Is an instantiation of a class template, that is, a class.

```
       boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (end - start)
```

Creates a temporary object of that type, initialized with the value of the expression `end-start`.

```
       boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (end - start).count()
```

Invokes the `.count()` method of the temporary object.

```
return boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (end - start).count();
```

Returns the result of the `.count()` method.

Answer (score 6):

This much: `boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (end - start)` is constructing an object, much like `int(x)` does.

Then `.count()` is called on that (temporary) object, and the return from that is what gets returned.

Answer (score 2):

There's three parts here. The first part is the simple `end - start`. I'm not familiar with Boost, but I'd wager that `end` and `start` do overload `operator-()` to subtract the two times and produce a `boost:chrono:duration<>` object.

This object is then passed in to the constructor for `boost::chrono::duration<double, boost::milli>`. I would guess that this serves to convert the duration from whatever format the subtraction provided to the one seen in this template, namely, `double`-precision duration that represents milliseconds.

Finally, the method `.count()` is called on this `boost::chrono::duration` object, which presumably returns the duration's value as a number (I'm guessing as a `double`).

Answer (score 1):

Actually `duration` is a data type, `(end - start)` evaluates to a parameter for the constructor.

Then `count()` is invoked on the constructed object and it happens to return a `double`, which is the first `typename` parameter to `duration`. (`duration <double, boost::milli>`)

Answer (score 1):

The code first constructs a temporary *unnamed* object of type `boost::chrono::duration<double, boost::milli>`, passing whatever `end - start` is to the constructor of that object.

It then calls the `count()` method on this new, unnamed object.

Whatever that method returns is what this function returns.